# Cannot kill - nginx: master process nginx -g daemon off

Tags: nginx, systemctl

I am setting up both Nginx and OpenRusty on my Ubuntu , one thing confuses me is , even after I quit OpenRusty and stop Nginx , I can still observe a nginx running , seems like this process cannot even be killed , My question is who launch this nginx and why this nginx daemon is always running ?

```
ps -aux | grep nginx
root      3779  0.0  0.0  10776  6180 ?        Ss   06:57   0:00 **nginx: master process nginx -g daemon off;**
systemd+  4587  0.0  0.0  11172  2756 ?        S    06:57   0:00 nginx: worker process
jia      17315  0.0  0.0  16184  1068 pts/0    S+   07:08   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

I tried systemctl to stop it , seems nginx still running

```
sudo systemctl stop nginx.service
 
 sudo systemctl status nginx.service 
● nginx.service - The NGINX HTTP and reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

 sudo ps -aux | grep nginx root 3779 0.0 0.0 10776 6180 ? Ss 06:57 0:00 nginx: master process nginx -g daemon off; 
    systemd+ 4587 0.0 0.0 11172 2756 ? S 06:57 0:00 nginx: worker process
```

Comment: how's about to use `kill 3779 4587`? or the Terminator Style:  `kill -9 3779 4587`

Comment: neither works , I tried both , after I killed them , new nginx boot up again

Answer (score 1):

OpenResty (assumed you meant OpenR**e**sty and not OpenR**u**sty!) is a toolset and an advanced configuration of nginx's http daemon. So it will always include a running nginx if openresty is running.

So for me your `ps -aux | grep nginx` results in:

```
...
root      8402  0.0  0.0  49984 14580 ?        SNs  Jul25   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
...
```

My config seems to include the full path, but if yours doesn't, you could try (replace `8402` with your nginx's pid):

```
sudo ls -l /proc/8402/exe
```

what, in my case, results in:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep 20 16:46 /proc/8402/exe -> /usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx
```

So the running nginx binary comes from OpenResty and not the "other" nginx. You might also consider removing the other nginx to not getting confused about the correct config files...